# Verb form of "drive" after "see" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, verb-forms

I saw him .... off.

A.drive
B.to drive
C.driving
D.driven

I chose C but the key is A. I don't know why. Can you help me explain the reason?

Comment: C or D would be valid usage, perhaps the question was explicitly asking for a particular tense or meaning?

Answer (score -1):

We have to know if there were any more details in the test (I fully agree with djna, see his comment).

A is 10x more frequent than C at Google Books; both are possible, but with different meanings:

> [How English Works: A Grammar Handbook with Readings](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gg16XC8hC8AC&pg=PA225&dq=%22saw%20him%20drive%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EccsVa3AOYalNrP2gLAJ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22saw%20him%20drive%22%20grammar&f=false)- Page 225 Ann
>   Raimes - 1998 - VERBS FOLLOWED BY EITHER -ING OR INFINITIVE (TO +
>   SIMPLE ...
>
> ***see, hear, watch, notice, observe***
>
> I saw you *driving* away. **(activity in progress)**
>
> I saw him *drive* away. **(the whole event)**

If no further details were given, it means that the 10x more frequent was considered known, or more generally that people more frequently report the whole event, than the activity in progress.

According to the classical

[A treatise on the grammatical analysis of sentences](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JXACAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22saw%20him%20drive%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=880sVeG6I4ewggScz4HoCg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22saw%20him%20drive%22%20grammar&f=false)By Walter Marlow Ramsay

*I saw him drive.*

is practically equivalent to

*I saw that he drove.*