# Why is the "to" in "we may see the price to rise" is wrong?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech, conjugation

My friend is trying to tell me that the use of "to" in the sentence "we may see the price to rise" (meaning "we expect the price to rise" or "we may see the price rise") is correct. I'm fairly certain this is wrong, but I cannot think of a way to definitively explain why. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: But is "we may see the price to rise" also correct?

Comment: Nope, not to my ear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["I saw him crossing" vs. "I saw him cross"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/i-saw-him-crossing-vs-i-saw-him-cross)

Comment: Related question, [Verb form of “drive” after “see” in a sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239170/verb-form-of-drive-after-see-in-a-sentence). Welcome to EL&U. For future questions, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on ELL.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292089/explanation-of-grammatical-structure-is-needed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After some verbs (including "see") followed by an object, we use the "bare infinitive" (without a "to" in front).

Comment: Your post answers only part of the question. -1) from me. Please see the duplicate questions I linked above and edit your answer. I will cancel my downvote after your edit. Please let me know when it is done.

Answer (score 2):

The to-infinitive is often used after an object to express a function that the object serves for the subject, as in:

> I have a dog to protect me. (The object's function is to protect the subject)

to express a necessary action that the subject needs from the object:

> I need you to finish the report by Friday.  (The subject needs the object to finish the report by Friday)

or to express the purpose of a subject's action:

> Every night, I give warm milk to him to help him fall asleep. (The purpose of the subject's action is to help the indirect object fall asleep.)

When **a subject observed/observes/will observe an object do/doing something**, the to-infinitive isn't used.

> We saw him hit a home run yesterday.
>
> She hears her neighbours fight every day.
>
> You will feel the medication take effect after an hour.

Comment: What makes you think your answer is better than those in the linked questions in the comments above? Don't you think the question is too basic for EL&U? What makes you think *him* is the **indirect object** in "I read a bedtime story to him"?

Comment: @Rathony I didn't see anything about the to-infinitive in the linked post and that is essentially what the OP is asking about.  I don't really have standards when it comes to helping people.

Comment: You are not answering my questions. The linked questions are all related with the OP's question on why to infinitive is not used and those answers  are far more comprehensive than yours. You follow the guidelines. That's the way you help this community. The way you help the OP is to ask the OP to go to ELL. Not answering this basic question which has multiple duplicates.

Comment: @Rathony The OP may not be able to infer the reason why the to-infinitive is not used from the above linked post. I don't understand the harm in answering a question.  Don't you think your time is better spent doing something else besides giving people a hard time?

Comment: Your answer is not correct. And you didn't answer my questions. [This answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292089/explanation-of-grammatical-structure-is-needed) is far more comprehensive than your answer. I don't see any harm answering a duplicate question. I would have downvoted your answer if I had judged that way. You edited the wrong part. That's not an indirect object.

Comment: @Rathony I gave the OP _an illustrative list_ of how the to-infinitive is commonly used in sentences. It wasn't a complete one obviously because I'd used the word "often."

Comment: What I don't understand is you gave the OP an *illustrative list* of how the to-infinitive is commonly used, It's not a full list though. However, why didn't you give the OP an *illustrative list* of how the to-infinitive is **not used** commonly? You used only **to see** as an example while rogermue's answer has a full (almost full) list.

Comment: I meant **to see** is related with all the verbs to express perception. How about verbs of cause and allowance:as in rogermue's answers? Your answer reads like only when a subject observes an object do/doing something, the to-infinitive is not used. Is **to feel** related with observation?

Comment: Then go ahead and edit your answer. Your answer is misleading. I will reverse my downvote when your edit is done.

Answer (score -2):

'To rise' is the infinitive form of the word, whereas 'rise' is a conjugated form. The key here is that you conjugate the first infinitive and then leave the second infinitive alone.

So, it goes something like this:

subject + **conjugation**

> We see.

subject + **conjugation** + direct object

> We **see** the price

subject + **conjugation** + direct object + **conjugation**

> I **see** the price **rising**.

subject + **conjugation** + direct object + *intransitive infinitive*

> I **want** the price *to rise*.

The sentence that *you* offered as a response:

> We expect the price to rise

Invokes the infinitive 'to rise' as an intransitive verb, which does not take a direct object.

I hope that helped!

(To those more knowledgeable than I, please feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken!)

Comment: I'm afraid this is wrong from beginning to end.  *Rise* here is an infinitive, but it's missing the introductory word *to*, so it's called a bare infinitive.  When to use which type of infinitive is a matter of idiom.  Conjugation involves the various inflections that finite verbs undergo to represent things like tense and number.  Infinitives aren't conjugated:  the verb is always the plain form, either active (*to see*) or passive (*to be seen*).  *Rising* is a present participle, which is not germane to the question.  Neither is the transitivity of the verb *to rise*.